# Scrolling with ionic css (without ionic.js)

Tags: css, scroll, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use ionic.css for styling an application. I read some posts that this is possible. [E.g. in this thread someone claims to use it with ko and durandal](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/the-status-bar-issue-on-ios7/94/2). So I've added the css and created some test content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>ChocolateChip-UI iOS</title>
        <link href="ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
            <h1 class="title">Music</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content has-header">
            <div class='list'>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
                <a class='item item-avatar'>
                    <img src="../images/Hurry and Harm.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <h2 >title</h2>
                    <p >text</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The app looks as expected, but the content doesn't scroll. How I can enable scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from this Ionic example: http://codepen.io/mvidailhet/pen/bVyNmz?editors=101

If we add `overflow-scroll="true"` to the ion-content element (which disable javascript scrolling and use the default scrolling), we can see in the DOM that Ionic added a class `overflow-scroll` to the `ion-content`and added an inner div with a `scroll` class. That's all you need to make your list scrollable with the Ionic CSS.

Here is a working Codepen: http://codepen.io/mvidailhet/pen/LpoEeW

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted :-)